# Wifi Connection Manager

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager

Just need some help on Android...I just want to know the basic steps in creating an application that would enable detection of all the WiFi networks in a given area and establishing connection with the desired WiFi network and also disconnecting it as and when required...

I would like to learn it on my own but would appreciate anyone providing with source codes...

Answer (score 1):

The key class to use would be the WifiManager. The documentation can be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html.